# using gganimate to animate line chart in r

Tags: r

I am trying to animate my line chart based on three countries in my data `df`.

here is my data:

```
co1<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10,12,14,16,18), cn= c(10.1,12.1,14.25,16.09,18.3), country ="USA")
co2<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.5,12.6,14.5,16.5,18.5), cn= c(10.6,12.5,14.3,16.7,18.6), country ="brazil")
co3<- tibble(age= c(10:14 ), pop=c(10.9,12.9,14.9,16.9,18.9), cn= c(11.9,13.9,15.9,17.9,19.9), country ="niger")
df<- rbind(co1,co2,co3)
```

by the code below, I have tried to animate my line chart but it does not work.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age,group = country))+
  geom_line(aes(y=pop),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=cn),colour="blue")+
  #facet_wrap(~country) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  xlab("age") + ylab("population")+
transition_states(country,transition_length = 2, state_length = 1)+
  labs(title = 'country: {closest_state}')
```

Comment: which animation do you wish to achieve?

Comment: @ maarvd I want to use transition_state, actually I want each chart changes based on country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code worked. Fixed the slight mismatch between closest_state and the country in the label.

```
#libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

#from wide to long
df <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("pop", "cn"))

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = value, group = country, col = name)) + geom_line() + 
  labs(x = "age", y = "population") + transition_states(country, transition_length = 3, state_length = 0) + 
  ggtitle("country: {closest_state}") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: I got this error : `transformr is required to tween paths and lines`

Comment: try to install ```transformr```